Gmail navigation pane shows Mail, Chat, Meet; prevents sticky display of mail folders and tags
For one of my accounts (let's call this the "afflicted account"), the Gmail navigation pane on left shows Mail, Chat, Meet. This prevents the mail folders from being permanently displayed, i.e., they always collapse out of view when I'm not hovering no the Mail icon. Clicking on the hamburger icon on the upper left doesn't do anything.
For other accounts, clicking on the hamburger icon allows me to pin the folder pane to the left so that they don't collapse away. How can I make the "afflicted account" behave this way?
Possibly helpful observations
The "afflicted account" is associated with an organization, whereas the other accounts are not. However, the IT person of said organization is not familiar with the webmail interface aspect of Gmail, i.e., the user side.
The non-stickiness of the folder pane also seems to depend on the network that I'm using.  For example, in the office, the folder pane is non-sticky.  At home, however, the hamburger icon does cause the folder pane to alternate between sticky and non-sticky.  I didn't even log out between home and office (I put the laptop to "sleep"), so I doubt that this change in behaviour is due to resetting a Windows or Chrome browser configuration.  I didn't even close the Gmail webpage.
